# How to capture the change of required attendees on Scheduling Assistant Tab?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

**Background**

Currently, we are developing an Outllok add-in using this template to show the required attendees and relevant meeting information in taskpane.
We are using Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees to get the required attendees of the appointment, and addHandlerAsync to get the change of thre required attendees, and use it to update the add-in in a real-time way.

*taskpane.js*

```
Office.onReady((info) => {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
      document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
      item = Office.context.mailbox.item;  

      //function to show the required attendees and relevant meeting information in taskpane
      updateTaskpaneContent();

      //Capture the change in attendees and update the taskpane
      item.addHandlerAsync(
        Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,()=>{
          updateTaskpaneContent();
        }
      );

      //Capture the change in dureation and update the taskpane
      item.addHandlerAsync(
        Office.EventType.AppointmentTimeChanged,()=>{
          updateTaskpaneContent();
        }
      );
    }
  });
```

**Problem**

It worked fine in Meeting tab but in Scheduling Assistant tab, the event handler cannot be triggered when the attendees are changed (Image below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEnVu.png)

**Expected Behaviour**

The following are what I want to achive:

1. When I add a required attendee from Scheduling Assistant tab, the event handler should be triggered.
2. When I uncheck the checkbox in front of the attendee from Scheduling Assistant tab, the event handler should also be triggered. (p1)
3. When I delete the attendee from Shceduling Assistant tab, the event handler should be triggered.

Comment: Which client (Outlook for windows or OWA or New Outlook on Windows) are you using?

Comment: Outlook for windows.

Comment: To be more specific, the version of Outlook is Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20908) 32 bit.